# Console.log returns json response with two objects of the same key name

Tags: json, reactjs, object, axios, key

I have an object with two nested objects with the same key names (data), the second object has a nested object with same name(data). I'm trying to access the number and letter keys of the nested second object. My goal is to select the second data object and 'ignore' the first one so it doesn't show up in my console.log as undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index.js  get api endpoint and return response.

```
const worldData = 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all';

export const fetchWorldData = async () => {
try {
     const response = await axios.get(worldData);

     return response;
   } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  } 
};
```

App.js set data to state object and pass it down to props

```
import { fetchWorldData } from './api';

 class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
     worldData: {},
    };

     async componentDidMount() {

         const fetchedWorldData = await fetchWorldData();

           this.setState({
            worldData: fetchedWorldData,
          });
      }

      render() {
       const { worldData } = this.state;

         return (
             <div>
                <WorldDisplay data={worldData} />
              </div>
                 );
                }
              }

   export default App;
```

Component with props

```
import React from 'react';


const WorldDisplay = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> hello world</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WorldDisplay;
```

This is what appears when console.log

```
{
{data: _proto_},
// I want to access nested data object below 
{data: data:{updated: 1594404341270, cases: 12507540, ...}
}
```

Comment: What you posted is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thank you, changed the title to reflect the issue.

Answer (score 2):

What you're actully getting are two console logs. The first one is blank or empty, so what it shows on console is it's **_proto** or *portotype* (inherited props and methods from its basic form; JS **Object** in this case)

The second log gets the response with actual data.
It does have only one prop: **data**. It's structure is

```
{
  config: Object
  data: Object
  headers: Object
  request: XMLHttpRequest
  status: Number
  statusText: String
}
```

What you want is the **data** prop inside this (so it's data.data) which contains this

```
{
  active: Number
  activePerOneMillion: Number
  affectedCountries: Number
  cases: Number
  casesPerOneMillion: Number
  critical: Number
  criticalPerOneMillion: Number
  deaths: Number
  deathsPerOneMillion: Number
  oneCasePerPeople: Number
  oneDeathPerPeople: Number
  oneTestPerPeople: Number
  population: Number
  recovered: Number
  recoveredPerOneMillion: Number
  tests: Number
  testsPerOneMillion: Number
  todayCases: Number
  todayDeaths: Number
  todayRecovered: Number
  updated: Number
}
```

To access it within your code, try this:

```
const WorldDisplay = (data) => {
  if(data.data && data.data.data)
      console.log(data.data.data);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> hello world</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: As mentioned in my post, when I console.log(data) and in this case console.log(data.data.data) I am returned two objects. undefined and { active: Number,  ...}. How can I essentially 'ignore' the first object with the prototype to only retrieve data from the second object.

Comment: I'm not a React Programmer so maybe I'm missing something about this being called twice, but I'd say you can put an *if* statement. So, if data.data contains anything, do something. If it's empty (if it has only the _proto_ it's practically empty), do nothing.
Does that makes sense?